# loading ajax value in html input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown with content )Course Title) from the database in the index.php file. I get dropdown selected data and send it to a PHP file. In PHP file using received (Course Title), I select related Course (Start Date) and (End Date) and send them to a PHP file using AJAX.

I have two input tags of type text, which I want its value to be related (Start Date) and (End Date) when users click a course title.

When I show the received (Start Date) and (End Date) in a div it is showing well, but when I want to set the values of input tags relatively start_date and end_date it is not showing anything.

I am new in ajax and jquery and don't know what is problem

following is my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="insert.php">
    <select name="training_title" id="dropdownList"">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
        require('db.php');
        $sql = "SELECT distinct(COURSE_TITALE) FROM [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[ETIS_Course_Final]";
        $params = array();
        $options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);
        $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
        if ($row_count === false)
            echo "Error al obtener datos.";
        else
            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
                ?>
                <option name="training_title" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></option>
                <?php
            }
        sqlsrv_close($conn);
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="start_data" id="start_data" value="">
    <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" VALUE="">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dropdownList').on('change', function () {
            var val1 = $("#dropdownList option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'test.php',
                data: {text1: val1},
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#result').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

and following is test.php file

```
    <?php
$text1 = $_POST['text1'];

require('db.php');
$sql = "SELECT distinct(STARTDATETIME) FROM [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[ETIS_Course_Final] where COURSE_TITALE='$text1'";
$params = array();
$options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);

if ($row_count === false)
    echo "Error.";
else
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
        echo $row['STARTDATETIME']->format('d/m/y');
    ?>
        <?php
    }
$sql1 = "SELECT distinct(ENDDATETIME) FROM [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[ETIS_Course_Final] where COURSE_TITALE='$text1'";
$params1 = array();
$options1 = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1, $params1, $options1);
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt1);

if ($row_count === false)
    echo "Error.";
else
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1)) {
        echo $row['ENDDATETIME']->format('d/m/y');
    ?>
        <?php
    }
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Comment: "when I want to set the values of input tags relatively start_date and end_date it is not showing anything"...where in the code are you doing that? I don't see any attempt to create or populate any input tags. Did you try? If so, please show your attempt and then maybe we can fix it. Without seeing the code, it isn't 100% clear what you wanted to do, or what the problem is. Thanks

Comment: "when I want to set the values of input tags relatively start_date and end_date it is not showing anything." Can you explaine ?

Comment: sorry for my poor English

Comment: actually I want to Get Content in text field dynamically, based on the dropdown selection

Comment: success: function (response) {
                    $('#start_date').val(response);
                }

Comment: Ok. So, the obvious problem with that code is that `response` does not contain a single date, it contains (at least) 2 dates. It would be better if PHP returned a JSON object with separate properties for each date. Then the JavaScript could select each individual date by its property name in the response object.

Comment: you mean I have to make changes in test.php file. if so could you please tell me how to how to return a JSON with separate properties by PHP.

Comment: Someone got there before me - see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return two values from test.php so it's better to use json return.Check below code :

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dropdownList').on('change', function () {
        var val1 = $("#dropdownList option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: {text1: val1},
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#start_data').val(response.STARTDATETIME);
                $('#end_date').val(response.ENDDATETIME);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and below is test.php code :

```
    <?php
    $text1 = $_POST['text1'];
    $return_array = array('status'=>false,'STARTDATETIME'=>'','ENDDATETIME'=>'');
    require('db.php');
    $sql = "SELECT distinct(STARTDATETIME) FROM [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[ETIS_Course_Final] where COURSE_TITALE='$text1'";
    $params = array();
    $options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);
    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
    if ($row_count === false){
        //"Error.";
    }
    else{
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
            $return_array['STARTDATETIME'] =  $row['STARTDATETIME']->format('d/m/y');
            $return_array['status'] = true;
        }
    }

    $sql1 = "SELECT distinct(ENDDATETIME) FROM [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[ETIS_Course_Final] where COURSE_TITALE='$text1'";
    $params1 = array();
    $options1 = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
    $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1, $params1, $options1);
    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt1);
    if ($row_count === false){
        //"Error.";
    }
    else{
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1)) {
            $return_array['ENDDATETIME'] = $row['ENDDATETIME']->format('d/m/y');
            $return_array['status'] = true;
        }
    }
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
    echo json_encode($return_array);
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: The only flaw in this is setting `$return_array['status'] = true;` in two different places. Just because it's true in one place doesn't make it true in the other place. Also, what's the purpose of this variable, even? It will be obvious to the calling code if any of the values are missing. Otherwise, this is a good approach.

Comment: status is used if we want to display error at front side when there is no data in database.

Comment: yes but, the front side can simply check if the date fields are null or not. A separate status isn't needed for that. Either that or, the server should return an appropriate HTTP error status code (which is a more RESTful solution). But anyway, your approach would not fulfil the requirement. For example if there is no "start" date, but an "end" date exists, status would still be true (and the same in the opposite case), so even if you want to use it, it doesn't do the job correctly

Comment: If end date is exist then we can display it in end date input right? And you can change response as you want now just requirements to fulfil.

Comment: yes, of course, but the requirements imply that there should be both dates present in every case. Anyway, we're getting off the main topic. It was a side issue I pointed out.

Comment: Then simple if there is one date is not present then we can make status false and front side can display error message as want.It's depends on requirements as I said.

Comment: Dear @kishan Thank you very much it is working well

Comment: Please mark answer as right answer if it helps you!